# JPA return HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> using Native or Named Query

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

i have a table with the folowing structure :

```
ID   id_client   id_order

1      1          10
2      1          15
3      1          13
4      2          20
5      2          40
6      2          9
```

my issue is : how to create  a query(named or native) that return the result as

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>
```

my map contains a unique id_client with an arrayList of all id_order:

```
1=>10,15,13

2=>20,40,9
```

note ; i'm using EclipseLink as a JPA implementation

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a query and build the map from the result. AFAIK there's no easy way to let EclipseLink build that map for you (although I'm using Hibernate and thus can't say that much about EclipseLink).

Comment: Not part of the JPA spec. Build it yourself as advised by Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how to deal with this issue ,
you should use Stream API.

```
 List<Entity> listEntity = yourservicenameTogetDataFromDataBase();

//grouping By id_client 
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupingMap = listEntity
      .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o->o.getIdClient()));

//result

for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : groupingMap.entrySet()) {
        System.err.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() +" , Values :");
          for (Integer  i : entry.getValue()) {
      System.err.println(i);

      }
  }

Key = 1 , Values :
  10
  15
  13

Key = 2 , Values :

  20
  40
  9
.....
```